# Is it possible to use SDL2 with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, sdl, smart-pointers, sdl-2, unique-ptr

I have this line of code

```
//std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window> _window_; // this is somewhere else...
_window_ = std::make_unique<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, _WIDTH_, _HEIGHT_, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));
```

it produces the following compiler error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from /home/user/prj/src/main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘typename 
std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = SDL_Window; _Args = {SDL_Window*}; typename 
std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window>]’:
/home/user/prj/src/main.cpp:36:170:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:791:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct SDL_Window’
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
```

why? (It works fine without smart pointers, so my guess is I didn't understand the syntax and this is trivial to fix. Will add source and `CMakeLists.txt` below.)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(prj)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(prj ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(prj main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prj ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

class Window
{

    public:

    Window()
        : _window_{nullptr}
        , _surface_{nullptr}
    {
        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            _window_ = std::make_unique<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, _WIDTH_, _HEIGHT_, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));

            if(_window_ == nullptr)
            {
                std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                _surface_ = std::make_unique<SDL_Surface>(SDL_GetWindowSurface(_window_.get()));
                SDL_FillRect(_surface_.get(), nullptr, SDL_MapRGB(_surface_->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(_window_.get());
                SDL_Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    ~Window()
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(_window_.get());
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    private:

    const int32_t _WIDTH_{600};
    const int32_t _HEIGHT_{400};

    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window> _window_;
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface> _surface_;

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Window window;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couple of questions about SDL\_Window and unique\_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424877/couple-of-questions-about-sdl-window-and-unique-ptr)

Comment: @lcs Edited question

Comment: `struct SDLWindowDestroyer { void operator()(SDL_Window* w) { SDL_DestroyWindow(w); } }; using SDLWindowPtr = std::unique_ptr<SDLWindow, SDLWindowDestroyer>;`

Comment: @user3728501 The answer to that question has the syntax in it.

Comment: @lcs They use a different syntax using structs. In which case my question becomes "what's wrong with my attempt".

Comment: @lcs ie; see the screenshot which I attached at the bottom of the question - there's a comment in the linked reference which isn't obvious

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Solution

Finally figured out the answer with a lot of trial and error, so will explain the solution here.

This is the correct syntax:

```
// first define the unique_ptr as member of class
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)> _window_;

// second, initialize in the member initialization list of class constructor
// probably don't need to do this if not embedding as member of class
class_name()
    : _window_(nullptr, SDL_DestroyWindow)
{
    // blaa blaa SDL code etc
    _window_.reset(SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));
}

// finally we need to be able to delete
// but this is handled automatically
```

## Explanation

When we add the unique_ptr as a data member, we need to give both the type `SDL_Window` and the "deleter function format / syntax", becuase an ordinary `delete` call is not correct. We use `decltype` to automatically construct the correct deleter format from the deleter function. (Perhaps not the most accurate explanation.) In a way, `decltype` is somewhat like auto...

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)> _window_;
```

This object must be initialized. We do this in the constructor. We set the pointer to `nullptr` (because we do not want to initialize it before initializing SDL2) and we also set the deleter function.

```
: _window_(nullptr, SDL_DestroyWindow)
```

After initializing SDL, we then want to create a window. This is done most easily by calling the smart pointer `reset()` function. We pass it a new pointer returned by the function which creates the window.

```
_window_.reset(SDL_CreateWindow(...));
```

Done. Took a long time to figure out but makes sense now. References

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

[Why does my unique_ptr think is has a null function pointer deleter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915631/why-does-my-unique-ptr-think-is-has-a-null-function-pointer-deleter)

[What's wrong with this initialization of unique_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853309/whats-wrong-with-this-initialization-of-unique-ptr)

Comment: A custom deleter is what you want, but note that your code can be improved further: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adc9e7f6bf45e0ca

Comment: @milleniumbug How? That doesn't look like an improvement to me

Comment: Refer to the link. Using a stateless function object reduces the size of the smart pointer, and you don't need to pass in the function to the constructor of `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Note that you don't need the constructor initializer. You can inline-initialize `_window_` directly: `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)> _window_{nullptr, SDL_DestroyWindow};`

Comment: @milleniumbug Apologies. I missed the point here (size reduction.)

Comment: @NikosC. No I can't due to the nature of how SDL works - if the same class calls `SDL_Init` then this won't work.

Comment: You're initializing to `nullptr`, so it will be fine. (Btw, I'm only refering to the member initializer list, not the `.reset()` call in the ctor body. That stays as-is, obviously.)

Comment: Oh, btw, in case it wasn't obvious, this is simply based on the fact that `unique_ptr` will not actually call the deleter if the managed pointer is null.

Comment: @NikosC. Oh, right I've just realized what you mean - thanks

Answer (score 2):

Those structures are [*opaque data structures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type), you don't have the full definition of them. That means, among other things, that the default `std::unique_ptr` deleter don't know how to "delete" the structures.

You need to provide your own custom deleter. For `SDL_Window` it's the [`SDL_DestroyWindow`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyWindow) function.

Comment: Which also means you don't use `make_unique` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A SDL Windows is destroyed using SDL_DestroyWindow, not plain delete, like the unique_ptr's default deleter does. You need to supply a custom deleter to unique_ptr, which will call SDL_DestroyWindow.